# Django 3.2 update AutoField to BigAutoField backward compatibility with foreign key relations

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm running into a problem after updating my project from Django 2.2 to Django 3.2.

In Django 2.2 primary keys are created using `AutoField` meaning in MySql they are considered `int(11)` and all foreign keys from this table must also be `int(11)`.

In Django 3.2 primary keys are now created with `BigAutoField` which in MySql creates type `bigint(20)`. Therefore, I can't create any foreign key relations with old tables.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/) this can be changed in settings using:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

This works in creating primary keys as `int(11)` however, foreign key fields are still being created as `bigint(20)` meaning a relation can't be created because they must be of the same type.

[Here](https://dev.to/weplayinternet/upgrading-to-django-3-2-and-fixing-defaultautofield-warnings-518n) says that you can change all your existing tables to `BigAutoField` but this also doesn't take care of foreign key relations.

Is there any way to change all primary keys and their relations to a different type easily? Am I missing something in the Django documentation where they also provide compatibility to related keys and well as primary keys?

I would obviously prefer to change all my existing data to work with `BigAutoField` if all future releases of Django will now use this as the default

Comment: Do we have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider updating the old database directly via the **MySQL** console? After that, you can add this *"old (updated)"* database to your project.